# BluetoothLePlugin use in angular

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins

i have get this Error: exec proxy not found for:: BluetoothLePlugin

constructor(public bluetoothle: BluetoothLE, public plt: Platform) {

```
plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
  bluetoothle.initialize({
    request: true,
    statusReceiver: true,
    restoreKey: `ugen-dashboard`
  }).subscribe((result) => {
 
    if (result.status === 'enabled') {
      bluetoothle.startScan({}).subscribe((status) => {
       
      });
    }
  });
});
}
```

Comment: are you setting up your project with `cordova run android --device` code?

Comment: @OnurÖzkır no 
i have use "ionic serve --cordova --platform browser"